# Vector of function pointers emptying itself

Tags: c++, function, pointers, vector

I was working on a project and started a new class. I wanted to use a vector to store pointers of functions and then call them. Getting the function pointer and calling it was not a problem, however storing them was. I tried storing them in a vector, but it keeps emptying itself. I've tried making the vector a member of a class and an extern, both don't work. I've never had this problem ever before, and I have no clue why this is happening. Here is my current code:

TickHandler.h:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <ctime>
 #include <vector>
 class tickHandler {
 public:
 void addTickingFunction(void(*func)());
 void onTick(void);
 std::vector<void(*)()>funcs;
 };
 extern tickHandler TickHandler;
```

TickHandler.cpp:

```
#include "TickHandler.h"
tickHandler TickHandler;
void tickHandler::addTickingFunction(void(*func)())
{
    funcs.push_back(func);
    std::cout << funcs.size() << std::endl;
}
void tickHandler::onTick()
{
    std::cout << funcs.size() << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i< funcs.size();i++)
    {

        funcs[i]();
    }
}
```

The expected output would be:

```
1
1
```

but instead it is:

```
1
0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: There is a lot of code in the project, but the class is only being accessed by 2 functions:

```
TickHandler.addTickingFunction(&physicsTick);
```

and

```
TickHandler.onTick();
```

Comment: I don't see anything shocking in what you posted. Please add the code you used to reach those outputs !

Comment: What is the rest of the code? I can probably guess, but it would still be useful to see it.

Comment: @Nbr44 That is all the code. There is a lot more code, but its only being touched by a two lines being: TickHandler.addTickingFunction(&physicsTick); and the   TickHandler.onTick(); function,

Comment: @MatsPetersson That is all the code. There is a lot more code, but its only being touched by a two lines being: TickHandler.addTickingFunction(&physicsTick); and the   TickHandler.onTick(); function,

Comment: Please post a minimal but complete program that demonstrates the problem. There is not enough information given here. In doing so, you may discover the error.

Comment: Yes, but you still need to show us that this happens in a small piece of code that is independent of all your other code, and isn't, for example, the result of goving over an array boundary and overwriting into `tickhandler`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Thats the weird part, I can't reproduce it anywhere else, BUT there. Very similar code is in the project, but that works fine.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong in what you have posted, so it's LIKELY something else (since compiler bugs in trivial code is pretty unusual).

Comment: *something* must be happening between when you add the ticking function, and when you call `onTick()`.

Comment: @Moo-Juice They were bing called in 2 different classes, but I changed it and it worked, but thats still going to be a problem. the add function is being called in a constructor, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'd suggest you put some guards around that header file, e.g.:

```
#ifndef TICKHANDLER_H
#define TICKHANDLER_H

    // Class declaration.

#endif
```

I am taking a shot in the dark here, but I think your problem is that you are adding your physics tick functions to *one* instance of a tick handler, but running them in *another*.  I don't think they are disappearing.

You've somehow got two instances of the `TickHandler` class lying about.  Given this is C++ and it is an object-orientated language, the `extern TickHandler` and the global instance created in your `.cpp` file is setting off alarm bells for me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right. But how could I fix this problem, I need to access Tick Handler from a lot of places.

Comment: Find out where you are declaring `TickHandler` (perhaps there is one in a class somewhere?), and make sure you're only using one.

Comment: Solved. The constructor doing the calls to TickHandler were before TickHandler was created, so it was sending the calls nowhere. Moved the calls and it works fine now. Thanks.

Comment: @BlueSpud, I am worried that you didn't get an error earlier - it doesn't send calls "nowhere", it *should* die a horrible death.

Comment: I agree, thats whats strange to me.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: Well, no, UB doesn't guarantee a crash. The only read being performed by addTickingFunction was probably to get the current container size during the push_back; static init rules guarantee at least zero-initialisation before code execution, so this member has memory allocated and would "read" 0 correctly, new memory would be allocated for the object, and the container size/pointer members then set to their new values.

Comment: (cont.) Later, when the vector is *really* initialised, both of these would reset to their on-construction defaults (say, back to 0 and a null pointer, respectively) and the objects initially falsely contained would leak. The point is that memory was available at all times and no operations were performed that relied on the initial state of that memory, which are the practical reasons that you *can* see a crash, when you invoke UB like this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, thanks for the clarification - that makes perfect sense.